# how to get jquery to recognize click event on a dynamically generated radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.product_name:radio').click(function() {get_products()} );
```

get_products() never gets called because this radio button was created after the page loaded.

I've tried the following, but they do not work.

```
$('.product_name:radio').on('click', function(){
    get_products() });

$('product_name.body').on('click', '.product_name:radio', function(){
    get_products()});
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is there no way to just place this code after the part where the radio button is added to the page? How is it being added?

Comment: It's being added dynamically

Comment: I've read the the original question in the link posted and still can't get it working which is why im posting this

Comment: The original answer should be an appropriate response to your question as well. To answer yours would just be to clone the answer from that post.

Comment: ive updated the OP with examples